# NSPopover with NSTextField programmatically

Tags: swift, macos-sierra

Created a function to show a little popover with a textfield inside. The popover show up correctly, but the textfield does not. The popover view controller is also created on the fly and this is what I tried:

```
func showLittlePopoverWithMessage(sender: AnyObject, message: String) {
    let controller = NSViewController()
    controller.view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(100), y: CGFloat(50), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(50)))

    let popover = NSPopover()
    popover.contentViewController = controller
    popover.contentSize = controller.view.frame.size

    popover.behavior = .transient
    popover.animates = true

    // let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(100,50,50,22))
    let txt = NSTextField(frame: controller.view.frame)
    txt.stringValue = message
    txt.textColor = NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.95)
    controller.view.addSubview(txt)
    txt.sizeToFit()
    popover.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
}
```

[image: pict of the problem]

So my question is why the text field does not appear.

Answer (score 4):

Well Guys, my own mistake. The textfield was too big and bad positioned, so for this reason the "message" sent was not visible. Fixed by initializing the NSTextField this way:

```
let txt = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(10,10,50,22))
```

now works as expected. Sorry to all to answer my own question, but I solved. The fact that I did not expect the field was nearly out of the view, so making the field bordered I was then being able to see his lower corner.